# Incorrect AES key length error while using python cryptography

Tags: python-3.x, aes, project

Edit: @erickson and @President James K. Polk both helped me with the problem. Thanks for addressing my query.

I'm trying to generate 256-bit keys for every password to encrypt the file(s) associated with it. Earlier, on a tiny snippet, SHA256 seemed to work for me - but there's a key length error now.

The functions snippets are as follows:

1. Key generation

```
def keygen(pa):
    hash_obj=SHA256.new(pa.encode('ascii'))
    key=hash_obj.digest()
    return key
```

2. Encryption

```
def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    message = pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)
```

3. Decryption

```
def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")
```

Upon initialising the program - where the CSV is generated, is where the problem arises.
The error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 84, in <module>
    decrypt_file('pwf.txt.enc',ki)

  File "", line 47, in decrypt_file
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)

  File "", line 40, in decrypt
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 232, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)


  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 274, in _create_cbc_cipher
    cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 93, in _create_base_cipher
    raise ValueError("Incorrect AES key length (%d bytes)" % len(key))

ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (7 bytes)
```

Comment: evidently the key you are supplying to `decrypt` is not the value that was returned from `keygen`.

Comment: @President James K. Polk I read somewhere that SHA generates the same hash for the same input. (Maybe a misinformation.) Assuming I used the password for the keygen initially, I thought it'd be ok to use the password as the input for the hash again - since I was unable to write a binary string to the CSV file. That didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear what you are trying to do, but this looks wrong to me:

```
hash_obj=SHA256.new(ki.encode('utf-8'))
key=hash_obj.digest()
decrypt_file('pwf.txt.enc',ki)
```

You are deriving a key (insecurely) from `ki`, but you assign it to `key`, and then use the original `ki` in the call to decrypt. Is that intentional?

If that is the problem, I'd blame the many alternate spellings for "key", which make your code hard to follow. Use descriptive names.

Also, a single round of SHA-256 is generally not a secure way to generate a cryptographic key from a password. Use an accepted key derivation algorithm like PBKDF2, which includes a salt and a work factor.

Comment: I see my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. For the key generator - I'll keep your tips in mind. Thanks again. :)